# ALTERing a sqlite table to add a timestamp column with default value

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, alter

It isn't possible to `ALTER table ADD column foo timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in sqlite, but are there any clever workarounds?

Comment: Uhm, the answer to that is 'it cannot be done' - which I state I know in my question. I'm asking for clever workarounds.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

SQLite does not actually modify the table contents when adding a column, so the default must be a value that does not require reading the table.

To work around this, you could use a trigger instead of a default value:

1. Add the column without the default value:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN foo timestamp DEFAULT NULL;
   ```
2. Use a trigger to set the default value:

   ```
   ADD TRIGGER MyTable_foo_default
   AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN NEW.foo IS NULL
   BEGIN
       UPDATE MyTable
       SET foo = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
       WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
   END;
   ```

Alternatively, modify the table contents first so that all rows have a value, *then* set the default value:

1. Add the column without the default value:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN foo timestamp DEFAULT NULL /* replace me */;
   ```
2. Set the column value to *something* in all rows (the actual value does not matter, the important thing is that all rows now have the new column):

   ```
   UPDATE MyTable SET foo = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
   ```
3. Change the default value (documentation: [PRAGMA writable_schema](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema), [sqlite_master](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master)):

   ```
   PRAGMA writable_schema = on;

   UPDATE sqlite_master
   SET sql = replace(sql, 'DEFAULT NULL /* replace me */',
                          'DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')
   WHERE type = 'table'
     AND name = 'MyTable';

   PRAGMA writable_schema = off;
   ```
4. Reopen the database (otherwise, SQLite won't know about the new default value).

Comment: The second solution feels like a better solution and feels like a very clever workaround! good stuff!

Comment: the first solution didnt work for me but the second solution worked well.

Comment: "The text in the sqlite_schema.sql column is a copy of the original CREATE statement text that created the object, except normalized as described above and as modified by subsequent ALTER TABLE statements."
https://sqlite.org/schematab.html

The part 3 didn't work for me, I just checked `select * from sqlite_master;`, it did not have the change made by `ALTER TABLE`. My default is still null :/.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier Works for me. What doess appear in the `sql` column for this table? Does it not have `DEFAULT NULL /* replace me */`?

Comment: @CL. I did the lengthy recreate table method instead. In the `sql` column, there was the original `CREATE TABLE` statement, without `foo timestamp DEFAULT NULL /* replace me */;` Any field added by `ALTER TABLE` was missing. That seem to correspond to the documentation I linked above.

Comment: @AmbroiseRabier That would imply that ALTER TABLE did not work at all. I'd guess that you were looking at `sqlite_master` from another connection, and the original had a transaction that was not yet committed.

Comment: I don't get what the `timestamp` type is given that sqlite does not have such a type.

Comment: @Alper SQLite allows any string as type. The type "timestamp" has numeric [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity).

Comment: It maybe necessary to also do `.dbconfig defensive off` before updating `sqlite_master`